# Math problems from a series of stories

Tags: support, questions

I want to write a long story (one chapter per question) and some of the chapters may be just math problems.

Where should I post those chapters?  Or, may I make some changes to those math problems so that they  can be fit on Puzzling?

Comment: I, umm, bump this question.

Comment: Is the idea that every chapter is a puzzle, and you would like to post them here? Is there a particular reason why some need to be "just math problems"?

Comment: Is this something you’re publishing somewhere and also want to post on Puzzling, or is it something you are specifically wanting just to put here? Not every creative endeavor fits here; if there are parts of what you’re creating that will be too math-problem to be proper puzzles, they won’t work as standalone puzzles. I’m guessing you won’t be able to publish the entire thing here; perhaps just posting (excerpts from?) the chapters that are suitable puzzles would be a workable idea?  I think we’d need more info on what you’re wanting to do to give a better answer than this.

Comment: I, umm, bump again.

Comment: @Rubio Question number 91047

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Some of the chapters are just math problems.

Comment: Bumping again while leaving pertinent questions in the comments completely unanswered is rather pointless.